# Reference is ambiguous with SparkSQL CSV

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read a bunch of CSV files in SparkSQL 2.10 with a custom schema that is partly Double, partly Strings like this:

```
// Build the schema
val schemaStringS = "col1 col2"
val schemaStringD = "col3 col4 col5 col6"
val schemaStringS2 = "col7 col8"
val fieldsString = schemaStringS.split(" ")
  .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))
val fieldsString2 = schemaStringS2.split(" ")
  .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))
val fieldsDouble = schemaStringS.split(" ")
  .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, DoubleType, nullable = true))
val schema = StructType(fieldsString ++ fieldsDouble ++ fieldsString2)

// Read DataFrame
val input = sqlContext.read.schema(schema)
  .option("header", true)
  .csv("/files/*.csv")
  .toJavaRDD
```

This results in

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'col6' is ambiguous, could be: col6#0, col6#5.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:129)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.foreach(StructType.scala:96)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.map(StructType.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileSourceStrategy$.apply(FileSourceStrategy.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:66)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:66)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.rdd$lzycompute(Dataset.scala:2547)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.rdd(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.toJavaRDD(Dataset.scala:2557)
    at com.otterinasuit.spark.sensorlog.main.Main$.main(Main.scala:39)
    at com.otterinasuit.spark.sensorlog.main.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

I tried merging the files with cat (only feasible for a PoC) and avoiding the CSV library (thinking this might be a bug in the new Spark version) but to no avail.

```
val input = sc.textFile("/csv/*.csv")
.map(line => line.split(",")).filter(row => !row.contains("col1")).map(x => Row(x))
val input2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(input, schema)
```

I have encountered this problem with regular DataFrames and joins and iirc this can be solved by specifying column names, dropping specific columns or using different joins. However, in this case, I don't have that option.

All headers in all files are identical, as proven by `head -1 *.csv`. I don't understand why this would occur.

Comment: just try with the `option("header","false")` and `option("inferschema","false")`

Comment: by doing header false , it will create its own columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `fieldsString` and `fieldsDouble` are refering to `schemaStringS`.

```
val fieldsString = schemaStringS.split(" ")
  .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))

//Changing from schemaStringS to schemaStringD
val fieldsDouble = schemaStringD.split(" ")
  .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, DoubleType, nullable = true))
```

So, when you are merging

```
val schema = StructType(fieldsString ++ fieldsDouble ++ fieldsString2))
```

It's throwing `'col6' is ambiguous` error,

Comment: Well that was embarrassing. Thank you!