# Spark[Scala]: Ambiguous groupBy column name

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So while testing I'm getting this error message:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'from' is ambiguous, could be: from, from.;
```

while testing but not when i run the part in the `spark-shell`...?

I'm doing a cross join on the following dataframes:

```
scala> timeSpanDF.show
+----------+----------+
|      from|        to|
+----------+----------+
|2018-01-01|2018-02-01|
|2018-01-01|2018-03-01|
|2018-02-01|2018-03-01|
+----------+----------+


scala> df.show
+------------+----------+--------+-----+--------------------+
|pressroom_id|     month|category|event|               email|
+------------+----------+--------+-----+--------------------+
|           1|2017-01-01| contact| open|somebody@example.com|
|           1|2018-01-01| contact| open|     me1@example.com|
|           1|2018-02-01| contact| open|     me1@example.com|
|           1|2018-02-01| contact| open|     me1@example.com|
|           1|2018-01-01| contact| open|     you@example.com|
|           1|2018-03-01| contact| open|     etc@example.com|
|           1|2018-02-01| contact| open|     me2@example.com|
|           1|2018-02-01| contact| open|     me2@example.com|
|           2|2018-01-01| contact| open|     me1@example.com|
+------------+----------+--------+-----+--------------------+
```

so I do this

```
val joinedDF = timeSpansDF
    .crossJoin(df)
    .filter(
        df("month") >= timeSpansDF("from") 
        && df("month") < timeSpansDF("to")
    )
    .distinct
```

and get this

```
scala> joinedDF.show
+----------+----------+------------+----------+--------+-----+---------------+
|      from|        to|pressroom_id|     month|category|event|          email|
+----------+----------+------------+----------+--------+-----+---------------+
|2018-01-01|2018-03-01|           2|2018-01-01| contact| open|me1@example.com|
|2018-02-01|2018-03-01|           1|2018-02-01| contact| open|me1@example.com|
|2018-02-01|2018-03-01|           1|2018-02-01| contact| open|me2@example.com|
|2018-01-01|2018-03-01|           1|2018-01-01| contact| open|me1@example.com|
|2018-01-01|2018-02-01|           1|2018-01-01| contact| open|me1@example.com|
|2018-01-01|2018-03-01|           1|2018-02-01| contact| open|me2@example.com|
|2018-01-01|2018-02-01|           2|2018-01-01| contact| open|me1@example.com|
|2018-01-01|2018-03-01|           1|2018-01-01| contact| open|you@example.com|
|2018-01-01|2018-03-01|           1|2018-02-01| contact| open|me1@example.com|
|2018-01-01|2018-02-01|           1|2018-01-01| contact| open|you@example.com|
+----------+----------+------------+----------+--------+-----+---------------+
```

Then later I want to aggregate this table like so, and this is where i get the weird message:

```
joinedDF.where(col("category") === lit(category) && col("event") === lit("open"))
    .groupBy("pressroom_id", "from", "to")
    .agg(count("email").cast("integer").as("something"))
```

which points to the groupBy. The strange part is that this works in the shell but when those operation are put into functions and tested with scalaTest they pull an error?

Whats up doc?

Comment: Could you please share your ScalaTest code. Would like to know how you are testing through ScalaTest.

Answer (score 1):

As I don't have a code to generate joinedDF and hence i prepared Dataframe myself to generate joinedDF.I have tested it in ScalaTest and it is working fine.

Please update your code as below.

```
val df = Seq(("2018-01-01", "2018-03-01", 2,"contact","open","me1@example.com"),
                ("2018-02-01","2018-03-01",1, "contact","open","me1@example.com"),
                ("2018-01-01","2018-03-01",1, "contact","open","you@example.com"),
                ("2018-02-01","2018-03-01",1, "contact","open","me1@example.com"),
                ("2018-01-01","2018-02-01",1, "contact","open","me1@example.com"),
                ("2018-01-01","2018-02-01", 1, "contact","open","you@example.com")).
      toDF("from", "to", "pressroom_id","category","event","email")

df.show() 

+----------+----------+------------+--------+-----+---------------+
|      from|        to|pressroom_id|category|event|          email|
+----------+----------+------------+--------+-----+---------------+
|2018-01-01|2018-03-01|           2| contact| open|me1@example.com|
|2018-02-01|2018-03-01|           1| contact| open|me1@example.com|
|2018-01-01|2018-03-01|           1| contact| open|you@example.com|
|2018-02-01|2018-03-01|           1| contact| open|me1@example.com|
|2018-01-01|2018-02-01|           1| contact| open|me1@example.com|
|2018-01-01|2018-02-01|           1| contact| open|you@example.com|
+----------+----------+------------+--------+-----+---------------+

val df1 = df.where(col("category") === lit("contact") && col("event") === lit("open"))
      .groupBy("pressroom_id", "from", "to")
      .agg(count("email").cast("integer").as("something"))

df1.show()



   +------------+----------+----------+---------+
|pressroom_id|      from|        to|something|
+------------+----------+----------+---------+
|           2|2018-01-01|2018-03-01|        1|
|           1|2018-01-01|2018-03-01|        1|
|           1|2018-02-01|2018-03-01|        2|
|           1|2018-01-01|2018-02-01|        2|
+------------+----------+----------+---------+
```

I have added import statement in my code.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: This looks exactly the same as what have...?

Comment: Yes.There were some typo in your code.I have tested the above code using ScalaTest and it's working fine. But i am wondering how you are getting error. Are you still getting same error with my code also??

Answer (score -1):

I am not a Scala expert, but I am a database administrator.

I suspect your problem originates from using the SQL reserved word `from` as a column name, since the stack trace shows that the Exception is originating from a Spark SQL module: `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException`.

Either:

1. Try changing the column name to something that is not a reserved word; or
2. Fully qualify the column name as `joinedDF.from`.

NB Your second code snippet refers to a dataframe named `timeSpanDF`, while your third refers to it as `timeSpansDF` (plural).

Edit: As a new member of the community, I don't have sufficient reputation to post a comment to @KZapagol's answer, but I believe that the essence of his answer is that there is a typo in the original poster's `joinedDF.where` clause: `col("category") === lit(category)` => `col("category") === lit("contact")`.

Comment: It looks like there is typo. I am just wondering how he is getting `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'from' is ambiguous, could be: from, from.` error as I have tested with ScalaTest and it is working fine.

Comment: Someone has downvoted my answer without leaving a comment.  My explanation does provide a rationale for the exception.  I guess we await feedback from the original poster.

Comment: There is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905709/reference-is-ambiguous-with-sparksql-csv, but in that instance the exception really was the result of duplicate column names in the query due to a typo.  That doesn't seem possible here.

Comment: yeah, its not a column name problem as I'm specifying `col("from")` which doesn't leave any room for ambiguity (or so I would think). The error seems like its a Spark bug, i mean `'from' is ambiguous, could be: from, from.;` is the period in `from.` significant?

Comment: In providing this answer, I have abstracted your query up one layer to think about what might the actual query statement be that Spark composes (I don't know with certainty how Spark handles this internally).  A "basic" SQL query is something like ```select columname from tablename```.  If your columnname is "from", then this could result in the formulation of an SQL query like ```select from from tablename```.  Did you try temporarily changing the column name?

Comment: @CpILL Also, have you retried your example, adjusting for the potential typos that KZapagol and I identified (the where condition change and the dataframe name differences)?

Comment: @CpILL I just noticed your comment to KZapagol's answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment on that answer.  I highlighted the difference in the edit to my answer.  The difference is the change in the where clause comparator from ```lit(category)``` to ```lit("contact")``` i.e. from using the column name to using the column value of interest.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, i was using a variable called `category` which i pass into the function that wraps that code

Comment: @CpILL Please edit your question and provide a "stand alone" example that generates this exception so that we can attempt to reproduce it.  According to the Spark documentation, ```lit()``` accepts a ```java.lang.Object``` parameter, but the returned ```Column``` object depends on the type of the parameter, which you haven't specified.

Comment: @CpILL Re your earlier comment asking whether the period in ```Reference 'from' is ambiguous, could be: from, from.;``` is significant, I have looked at the Spark source code, and it isn't.  Your stack trace is incomplete, but the origin of the ```AnalysisException``` is in ```org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.scala```.  The exception template was: ```"Reference '$name' is ambiguous, could be: $referenceNames."```, so the trailing period is from the template. LogicalPlan was refactored in May 2018 and that exception call was removed.  What version of Spark are you using?

Comment: @JimK I'm using Spark 2.2.0. I've had this error a few times where it is referring to the same column twice. The error seems to have stopped and i;m not sure why...?

Comment: @CpILL I suspect your problem was a typo rather than a Spark bug, but the latest 2.2.x release is 2.2.3 and 2.4.0 was released in Nov 18.  NB I have just noticed that you might also have one or more typos in your ```timeSpan``` data, since the first row spans one month and the second spans two months.  That is causing January rows to appear twice in ```joinedDF```.